# Hide control within a table with filter applied

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML (in my AngularJS page):

```
<input id="search-term" type="search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="vm.term.search" autocomplete="off" no-dirty-check>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="l in vm.logData | filter:{ Title : vm.term.search}">
        <td>{{l.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{l.Name}}</td>
        <td>
            <a id="resUp" ng-click="vm.resolve(l)" ng-show="vm.showResUpButton($index)">ResUp</a>
            <a id="resDown" ng-click="vm.resolveDown(l)" ng-show="vm.showResDownButton($last)">ResDown</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            ....
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Snippets from my controller for the methods above

```
vm.search = function (filter) {
    vm.term.search = filter;
};

vm.showResUpButton = function ($index) {
    //console.log(vm.term.search);
    return ($index > 0 );
}
```

Very new to AngularJS and amending an existing system we have.

At present everything works as intended. Page is loaded with data and i have a search box where i can enter some text and it narrows down the table with that search criteria.
Removing the search term brings back the data as if i loaded the page for the first time.

The `showResUpButton` (and the down but the code is almost identical so i havent posted that) shows the **resUp** *anchor* tag depending on if the index is above 0 (no point showing the 'a' tag for the first row)/

As i say all works as intended.

The problem i have come across is `resUp` (Id of the control) **should be hidden** if a search term is filled in, as the filter kicks in and therefore the functionality of this button should not be available when a filter/search term is active.

I have tried to add code such as

```
return ($index > 0 && vm.term.search != 'undefined');
```

and various length checks against `search` but i get odd errors such as the first row displaying when it shouldnt be (as this is based on the `$index` value, if the value is above 0 then to display that control otherwise not to)

Not sure what i could do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have trouble using functions as ng-show and ng-if. One of the issues is those functions run many many times as the scope digests, another might be nested scopes. Not sure what the exact issue is here, but a simple boolean expression would suffice

```
<a id="resUp" href ng-click="vm.resolve(l)" ng-show="vm.term.search==''">
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.vm = {
      term: {
        search: ''
      },
      logData: [{
        Title: 'One',
        Name: 'value1'
      }, {
        Title: 'Two',
        Name: 'value2'
      }, {
        Title: 'Three',
        Name: 'value3'
      }]
    }

  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input id="search-term" type="search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="vm.term.search" autocomplete="off" no-dirty-check>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="l in vm.logData | filter:{ Title : vm.term.search}">
        <td>{{l.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{l.Name}}</td>
        <td>
          <a id="resUp" href ng-click="vm.resolve(l)" ng-show="vm.term.search==''">ResUp</a>
          <a id="resDown" href ng-click="vm.resolveDown(l)" ng-show="vm.term.search==''">ResDown</a>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```